# Outlook AddIn Submission Failure due to Insufficient Interaction

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-app, office-store

I have submitted an update to a previously accepted Outlook Addin. I got a certification failure from my submission stating:

> Your offer demonstrate insufficient interaction with our service in Message Read mode. Please consider adding functionality which either reads information from or writes information to the Office Client.

Please help me to understand and solve this issue.

Comment: I will try to follow up with someone on the validation team, but it is likely that the validation team didn't found that you weren't interacting with the loaded mail item, when the add-in taskpane is open? (but I'm not sure what your add-in does)

Comment: Add-ins must show visible interaction with the Microsoft Office Product that they are designed to work with. The add-in should read some information from the email it is launched on and display it in the taskpane. For assistance on Microsoft Commercial Marketplace, AppSource Certification issues, please sign-in to your Partner Center account and go to https://aka.ms/marketplacepublishersupport  *Browse topics *Category: Commercial Marketplace *Create ticket, continue and Provide issue details. Complete the issue details and then Submit. A partner Support representative will follow up with you.